# Aframe - Setting opacity to `a-sky` element does not work

Tags: aframe, webvr

I have two overlapping a-sky elements. Second one is positioned at z=-1000 (not visible to camera). In this setup if I set opacity of first a-sky element to 0.5, I should see second a-sky element.

Following code does not work. (Need to make this work.)

```
skyEl.getObject3D("mesh").material= new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("image url"),
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.5
});
```

But this method works.

```
skyEl.setAttribute('src','image url'); 
skyEl.getObject3D("mesh").material.transparent = true;
skyEl.getObject3D("mesh").material.opacity= 0.5;
```

In my project I can't set src attribute because textures are already loaded and I can only create material from preloaded texture. I need to know what's wrong with first method and how to fix it. Is there some other parameter I need to set

Also tried using `a-sphere` instead of `a-sky` but same result.

DEMO: https://codesandbox.io/s/qx6zj247l6 (Covers both cases and please ignore all react & tween stuff.)

PS: Creating a crossfade + zoom scene transition effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the correct render order for transparency to work as intended is difficult. From the [material component documentation page](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/material.html#transparency-issues):

> **Transparency Issues**
>
> Transparency and alpha channels are tricky in 3D graphics. If you are having issues where transparent materials in the foreground do not composite correctly over materials in the background, the issues are probably due to underlying design of the OpenGL compositor (which WebGL is an API for).
>
> In an ideal scenario, transparency in A-Frame would “just work”, regardless of where the developer places an entity in 3D space, or in which order they define the elements in markup. We can often run into scenarios where foreground entities occlude background entities. This creates confusion and unwanted visual defects.
>
> To work around this issue, try changing the order of the entities in the HTML.

To resolve your case, simply place `#sky1` after `#sky2` in the HTML:

```
render() {
    return (
      <Scene>
        <Entity id="sky2-wrapper" rotation="0 90 0">
          <Entity id="sky2" primitive="a-sky" position="0 0 -1000" />
        </Entity>
        <Entity id="sky1" primitive="a-sky" opacity="1" />
        <Entity
          camera={{
            far: 10000,
            fov: 80,
            near: 0.05,
            active: true
          }}
          id="cam"
          rotation="0 90 0"
          mouse-cursor
          look-controls="reverseMouseDrag:true"
        />
      </Scene>
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Wow... Thank you. It worked. Funny thing is I already tried this on my actual project and it didn't work. Turns out there was a bug which caused the scene to render white. I'm an idiot. :/

Comment: @AKT if your real use case is more complex, an alternative to manual ordering is to let the THREE.js renderer attempt to sort automatically with `renderer.sortObjects = true`. More info in this A-Frame issue: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/666#issuecomment-335895847